# Can not get python to install Talos package

Tags: python, scipy, tensorflow2.0, talos

I've installed the latest python version 3.9.7 on my ubuntu 20.04 machine. I'm attempting to run some code that requires the Talos package, however I've attempted several times to install Talos using pip3.  It does much of the work downloading and installing stuff, until it gets to something called "building wheel for scipy", and then after a lot of work, all I get is error messages.  My first question is, is it possible that there is no version of Talos for 3.9.7, or that 3.9.7 is too advanced?  If it should integrate Talos, how can I diagnose the problem so I can get it installed?  Thx. J

Answer (score 0):

This could be because the wrong version of Cython is being picked up. I have experienced this being the cause of scipy build errors in the past. I would try a `pip3 install --upgrade cython` first.